# How can i modify a var value inside a function?

Tags: java, android, variables, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I wanted to set up this variable called userName, which should get a new value inside the ValueEventListener. However, when setting the new value inside the function, it doesn't change. The output is still ""

```
private fun getName(){

    var userName = ""
    val user = fbAuth.currentUser
    var uid = user!!.uid

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("not implemented")
                }
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    userName = snapshot.child(uid).child("name").getValue().toString()
                }
    })

    println(userName)


}
```

Expected output: John (value of name child),
current output: ""

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The listener is asynchronous, if you put the println statement below the `username =` line, then it will print.

In fact, go ahead and do that; observe the timestamps; which one prints first? The empty one or the one inside the callback?

the var *is being modified* by the callback, but the `println` executes first, long before (in computer times, that is) Firebase emits its value.

Additionally, I would invert the order of the `mDatabase` lines.
You are essentially requesting a value and then listening for results; the result may have already been emitted. You should add the listener first, then request the data.

### Update: what if I need the value for another callback?

Welcome to the world of asynchronous programming :-)

What you describe is a set of independent asynchronous operations. You need value A, and value B, but you can't obtain value B, until you have value A. Both are asynchronous and take time, but you don't have time on the main thread, or rather, you have ~16ms to compute, measure, and draw your screen so the OS can keep up with 60 frames per second. That's not a lot of time and part of the reason why asynchronous programming exists!

[This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57366256/2684) already provides a working sample of what you need. [This other external link](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html) has a more concrete example of the Observer Listener pattern.

In short, what you want is an instance of an object which can be invoked once the an operation completes.

In a regular synchronous function, each statement is executed after the other and no statement will be executed until the previous one is not finished; all statements are therefore, *blocking* statements.

For example:

```
var times = 2
var message = "Hello"
var world = "World"
println("The message is $message $times")
println(world)
```

Will print:

```
The message is Hello 2
World
```

This is because the execution point will go from one line to the other, waiting for the previous one to execute. If one operation takes time, the thread will be blocked (from performing anything else) until that operation completes and the execution point can move to the next instruction.

As you can imagine, the Main Thread in iOS and Android (and well, Windows, macOS, Linux, etc) cannot be blocked, or the OS wouldn't be able to respond to your touches and other things happening (for e.g., on a mobile phone, an incoming phone call wouldn't be able to be processed if the UI is not responsive and you cannot tap "answer").

This is why we use other "threads" to off-load things that are not super fast. This comes with a mindset change, as well as correct planning, for things are now more complicated.

Let's see a simple example (some pseudo code, so bear any obvious glaring mistakes, this is just to illustrate the point, not to write a solution).

```
fun main() {
    var hello = "Hello"
    var message = thisTakesTime()
    println("The message is $hello $message")
    println(hello)
}

fun thisTakesTime(): String {
    // do something that takes 1 second (1000 ms)
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    return "World"
}
```

This will print

```
The message is Hello World
Hello
```

As you can see, nothing changed, except that for one entire second, the main thread was unresponsive. If you were to run this on Android, for example, it will work, but your app will not respond for a second, during the Thread.sleep. One second is fast, try 10 seconds; this exceeds the Android Operating System limit of 5 seconds for the main thread to be unresponsive, before deciding the ANR (application not responding) dialog is needed; this is the infamous "It looks like XXX application is not responding, wait or close".

What can you do?

Initially, if you have too many callbacks (where callback A cannot execute until callback B finished, and callback B cannot execute until callback C finished), and you start nesting them like that, you end up in the infamous [Callback-Hell](http://callbackhell.com/) (in Javascript, but valid for any language/platform).

Basically tracking all these asynchronous callbacks and ensuring that *by the time the response comes*, your next callback is ready, and so forth is a pain, and it introduces exponential complexity if, for example, callback C fails in the middle, now you have to let callback B know that C failed and therefore it will have to fail too, which -in turn- has to let callback A (the original!) know that B failed, and therefore A has to do something about it, does A need to know that B failed because of C? or does A only cares for B and B alone and the reasons behind B's failure are irrelevant?

Well, as you can see, even talking about this gets complicated and messy and I didn't even cover other possible scenarios, equally as complex.

What I'm trying to say here is not that you shouldn't use callbacks; it's that you have to carefully plan where, and when to use them.

Kotlin has alternatives to reduce/remove the callback hell by using [Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) but these are a moderately advanced topic and it also requires a fundamental change in how you design your components and pieces.

All in all, for your use case, remember the golden rule of OOP: Make small concrete classes that do very few things, and do them well. If you need to start adding too many `if ()` all over the place, then chances are you're mixing business logic, random decisions, and "whatabout" cases all over the place.

Imagine you have a class that processes Location data and uploads it to a server.

You may be tempted to:

1. Write all the code in the Activity/Fragment (or ViewModel); quickly becomes a mess.
2. Create a LocationUtils with static methods (or singleton pattern); a mess already, but also hard to test, and mock. What if you need more than one type of processing? Or what if you want to store them in a database, are you going to add more static methods?
3. Create a small LocationProcessor class, that receives two points (lat/long) does the processing in a small function, and returns the processed data, then create another class called LocationUploader, that receives clean input from a Processor, and uploads it to a server. None of these classes should think about "what if I don't have permissions, what if the user turns location off", etc. These are problems that exceed the responsibility of a class whose intention was to process location coordinates, nothing else. There should be other classes responsible for that. Remember, *small classes, small responsibilities* == less to worry about in a single file.

#### Conclusion?

Well, at this point there are better answers which will give you the copy-paste version of what you're looking for; I believe the concept you have to take out of this wall of text today, is that in order to write modern, testable, and simple functional code, a change in how you plan things must happen.

Long story short: when things are not synchronous, you need to keep something (an object) ready to be called back (hence the name callback), listening (or observing) (hence why we call them listener or observers), the emission of something (usually called an Observable, because it can be "observed").

Good luck!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help :) Unfortunately, I want to use the emitted data from the first Listener as a parameter for another Listener to emit its value. I know, I probably should've mentioned that in my question. Do you know a way I can solve this? Again, Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Hey Nick, welcome to SO. What you're describing is a common case of the observer-listener pattern used since the beginning of time (well not that much) :). I'll update the question though [this other answer -in kotlin-](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57366256/2684) may give you a hint. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the listener is asynchronous, it will only work if you  print the variable inside onDataChange method.

However you can use a callback strategy to wait for Firebase to return the data. Something like this:

```
interface MyCallback {
    fun onCallback(value: String )
}

fun readData(myCallback: MyCallback){
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            userName = snapshot.child(uid).child("name").getValue().toString()
            myCallback.onCallback(value)
        }
    })
}

fun test(){
    readData(object: MyCallback {    
        override fun onCallback(value : String) {
            println(value)
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Martin says, it's an asynchronous operation, you should handle the text output after the asynchronous process has completed:

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                    TODO("not implemented")
                }
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    userName = snapshot.child(uid).child("name").getValue().toString()
                    println(userName) //--> Asynchronous request has ended, show the name
                }
    })
```